# Foreign Key tuple constraint multiple tables.

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables, and would like to create a new table which has 3 columns which are foreign keys to the other 3 tables ids.

```
CREATE TABLE tableABC(
    tblA INTEGER REFERENCES tableA,
    tblB INTEGER REFERENCES tableB,
    tblC INTEGER REFERENCES tableC,
    newColumn Integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (tblA, tblB, tblC)  ----- Is this efficient ?
);

CREATE TABLE tableA(
  tableA_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE tableB(
  tableB_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE tableC(
  tableC_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Now for table `tableABC` I would like the column pair (`tblA, tblB, tblC)` to be `unique`. When querying this table, search will be based on those three columns. Which way would be most efficient.

I did some search and could not find a way to have foreign key constraint on 3 columns from 3 different tables.

For example  `FOREIGN KEY (b, c) REFERENCES other_table (c1, c2)` references one table. Is it possible to reference 3 different tables.

Tnx.

Comment: Your code seems to work as written, as long as you move `CREATE TABLE tableABC` to the end.

Comment: What does "I would like the column pair (tblA, tblB, tblC) to be unique" mean? Three columns is not a pair, and your primary key constraint will make that combination of three columns unique.

Comment: Yea I mean tuple (tblA, tblB, tblC) be unique. Question is which would be more efficient when searching this table and if using foreign key tuple is possible...

Comment: Which *what* would be more efficient? If you always specify values for all three columns, the automatically generated index on the primary key is probably fine. If not, you might need to create separate indexes on columns "tblB" and "tblC".

Comment: @SpartanElite Can you please add a data sample?